# How can I change IFRAME height when the source it's on another domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, height

I think this option is not avaiable, but maybe you know some strategies for doing it!
I'm on http://www.mydomain.com, and I put an iframe with jquery of another domain :

```
​<div id="myContent​​​​​​​"></div>​

$('#myContent').html('<iframe id="myFrame" src="www.anotherdomain.com"></iframe>');​
```

Well, the page that I load, www.anotherdomain.com, it's mine, so I can add any kind of code!

What I'd like to do is set the height of `myFrame` regard the real size of the loaded page (which I can't know, it can changes during the time).

Is there a method where I can comunicate to the parent DOM (mydomain.com) the size of the inserted page (anotherdomain.com)?

I don't know it, I dubt so, but why don't ask.

Comment: as long as the same origin policy is not violated you can access the DOM of the iframe (or the parent from the iframe) via the usual DOM functions and check the size and resize accordingly

Comment: well, so in my case this policy is violated, right? :)

Comment: Cross-domain communications are very limited, and impossible depending on the on the remote host.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/  You can use JSONP to try and retrieve information from the remote site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found for that was to pass iframe height via url. You can find my test here :

http://jsfiddle.net/Grsmto/nBWrJ/2/ **(updated)**

This solution works cross browsers (chrome, ff, ie all versions, mobile etc.) and cross domain.

You MUST have access to the iframe code itself AND the iframe host.
You can refresh the iframe height when you want (even if content change) just by calling the publishHeight() function inside your iframe.

This should work without jquery (mostly writen in pure javascript...). 
The only inconvenient is that you will have the height in the url like :

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html#1458px
```

But you should easily remove it or change it to something less ugly.

**EDIT :** It seems that Disqus and Twitter use this library to do that : http://easyxdm.net/wp/

**EDIT 2 :** On your page you put the code on the first jsfiddle page. In your iframe you put the code of the iframe (the red div "myiframe" in bottom right). Hope it's clear...
But check my link below it should be a better and easier solution.

Comment: Could be a great solution! Unfortunatly I don't understand the code (which code put on my iframe, which on iframe host...). Can you explain it better?

Comment: Also, I don't see the definition of `publishHeight()`?

Comment: Sorry my jsfiddle was wrong ! Here is the good one : http://jsfiddle.net/Grsmto/nBWrJ/2/ I edit my post.

Comment: But in fact your example still doesnt work? On http://jsfiddle.net/Grsmto/nBWrJ/2/ the iFrame height is still 400px, not 3000px as `<div>my iframe</div>​` in http://jsfiddle.net/Grsmto/nv4Z3/

Answer (score 2):

You can send messages (such as the height of the frame) between iframes on different domains using postMessage:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: I think this will fails on every version of IE? :)

Comment: This is probably worth a read too: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain communications are very limited, and impossible depending on the on the remote host.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/  You can use JSONP to try and retrieve information from the remote site, but its very trying and not for beginners.

The work around that I found that worked for me was I used a server side language instead to include the remote file.  so instead of < iframe >

I did a PHP server-side include like:

```
<?php include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2'; ?>
```

This of course only applies if you are using PHP.  Once I included it that way I was able to manipulate the DOM elements.

Comment: But where do you include it? on a iframe right? So what's the differences?

Comment: no, not on an iframe, just in your code.  You don't use an iframe at all. If you go the iframe route you have to deal with cross-domain communication, which I stated is a very difficult route.  You will not be able to automatically detect the height of the iframe without JSONP.  You have a dead-end road unless you use another method such as JSONp, or what I suggested, including the PHP in the body of your code wherever you want the content to be included.

Comment: yeah, in fact what I need...my is a cross-domain communication :)

Comment: Then use JSONP if it absolutely has to be an iframe,  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/ .  However, this is only under the assumption your site you are trying to access accepts JSONp.  If it does not, you are out of luck